# merge elements with same keys of a yii2 model by adding their elements

Tags: php, yii2

The code in my controller action:

```
$model = ExamsExamResults::find()->where(['student_id'=>$student_id, 'exam_short_code'=>$test])->all();
$model = ArrayHelper::map($model, 'component_name','obt_marks', 'subject_code');
json_encode($model);
```

gives me following output:

```
{

    "002": {
        "Written": 15
    },
    "004": {
        "Practical": 45
    },
    "005": {
        "Practical": 45,
        "Written": 45
    }
}
```

I would like to add `obt_marks` for each `subject_code` so as to get an output similar to the following

```
{
    "002": {
        "marks": 15
    },

    "004": {
        "marks": 45
    },
    "005": {
        "marks": 90, //45+45

    }
}
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762365/php-merge-array-with-same-keys-and-one-same-value) question gives some hints but I think Yii community will be benefitted by knowing how to do in a more Yii2 fashion (but still pure php solutions are also welcome).

Comment: I think the outputs is wrong? `"002"` should be grouped together

Comment: I edited the question, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: I think, you can achieve this by two ways: 1) Using appropriate `->groupBy('student_id')` in query alongside `->sum('mark')`. 2) Using `array_reduce()` call on `$model` built by ArrayHelper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the solution in pure PHP you can use following to quickly sum up everything

```
$model = ArrayHelper::map($model, 'component_name','obt_marks', 'subject_code');
$output = [];
foreach($model as $k => $v) {
       $output[$k]['marks'] = array_sum($v);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [002] => Array
        (
            [marks] => 15
        )

    [004] => Array
        (
            [marks] => 45
        )

    [005] => Array
        (
            [marks] => 90
        )

)
```

Comment: vote up for a working solution. Isn't there any helper function in yii that can do the job?